# Google Test Linking Error: File was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (macOS)

Tags: googletest

I'm trying to get Google Test (their C++ Unit Testing Framework) working on my Mac, but I'm having an issue when trying to compile the library.

The following commands run fine:

```
export GTEST_DIR="path/to/g/test/"

g++ -std=c++11 -isystem ${GTEST_DIR}/include -I${GTEST_DIR} \
    -pthread -c ${GTEST_DIR}/src/gtest-all.cc

ar -rv libgtest.a gtest-all.o
```

When trying to actually compile my unit tests, I get a linking error saying *"libgtest.a: File was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86/64)"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be something Macs don't like with the command:

```
$ ar -rv libgtest.a gtest-all.o
```

Replacing this command with the one below fixed my issue:

```
$ libtool -static -o libgtest.a gtest-all.o
```

I wrote a simple script to automate the cloning of the Google Test library, then build and link it. All that is required is adding this script to your main project directory, giving it execute permissions (e.g. running `$ chmod 777 googleTestSetup.sh`, then `$ ./googleTestSetup.sh`)

https://gist.github.com/eagi223/0ba30b0b36b18f4de07943d9228dd73a